# CSS border around pic

Tags: css, image, border

There is a border around the pics on this site www.waynesboroheritagefoundation.com but the way that the achieve this border is by placing a border around the image in photoshop, or whichever program that they use.

I was wondering if it is possible to achieve the same, or similar, effect using just css?

I think that a purely CSS solution would be much more flexible and you wouldn't have to worry about the load time for an image (which I know is not generally a great concern now but I am old school.  :) )

Thanks for reading and any suggestions!
Jim

Comment: What have you done so far? please post your code

Comment: don't see any special kind of effect there, you can just use the CSS `border`.

Comment: You can put the image in the div and give border to that div.

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean this effect:

[image]

As you can see, it is in the picture itself, made with some kind of photo editor.

You can also do it with pure CSS, by wrapping your image in a span (or some other element):

HTML:

```
<span><img src='...' /></span>
```

CSS:

```
span {
    padding: 5px;
    background: white;
    display: inline-block;
    -moz-box-shadow:    0 0 3px 3px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #ccc;
    box-shadow:         0 0 3px 3px #ccc; 
}
```

Live demo: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qH4ge/).

**EDIT**

Based on [King King](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1679602/king-king)'s excellent comment, an even better solution is to add a white border to the image instead of wrapping it in a span.

```
img {        
    display: inline-block;
    border: 5px solid white;
    -moz-box-shadow:    0 0 3px 3px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #ccc;
    box-shadow:         0 0 3px 3px #ccc; 
}
```

Check [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qH4ge/1/).

Comment: Thanks LinkinTED for the quick response.  This works great except for one thing.  On the top right the border disappears completely.  You can look at it here - http://kevin-test.site90.net/Testing/  I tested with IE, Chrome and FireFox and have the same issue in all three.

Comment: Never mind!  I forgot that I had a spacer between the pics.  Eliminating that got rid of the problem.  Thanks again, Jim

Comment: why do we need a wrapper of span here? just apply the (white) border style on the `img` http://jsfiddle.net/qH4ge/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
 padding: 5px;     // how wide the border has to be
 background: white;// border colour (in this case)
 display: inline-block;
```

the white border can be given by putting above code.

further read : http://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/